# Manage PDF downloads and protected pages

Tags: plugins, login

I am re-building an old CMS site (I think it was built using Front Page) to update its appearance, and usefulness.  Have successfully completed most of its structure and content, but am quite uncertain as to how I can implement 2 new and different page types.

I need one page to show a 2-column, 13-row table which will contain hyperlinks for current year's and previous year's monthly newsletters (which would be uploaded as PDFs). Cannot find how to do this.

My second problem is that I wish to have 1 to 3 separate pages that would require logins/registration for privacy.  (All other pages on this site are Public).  Each page would address a different population, so most names would not repeat from one page to another, but a few will.  Again cannot find a method to implement this.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction? Would most appreciate it...

Comment: I have removed the question for a plugin recommendation (that would be off topic here). But please ask separate questions for each question.

Answer (score 1):

I think, What you are asking is, actually creating custom page templates concept,
Read this, and create your own pages as much as you want with your own design, they will appear in page editor right sidebar "template" section list.
Code them with your desired logged in/ logged of users, include them in "menu" section. With a template, then you can create pages for a specific pattern as in template.

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-custom-page-templates/
http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates